# Material going to oposite side in procedural mesh creation

Tags: unity, c#, 3d-meshes, mesh

Tried to instantiate this gameobject procedurally, material texture went to the other side:

```
public class tileCreator: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tileSize = 1;

    public Material tileMaterial; 
 
        void Start(){
 
        GameObject tileObject = new GameObject("Tile");

        MeshFilter meshFilter = tileObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();

        MeshRenderer meshRenderer = tileObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

        MeshCollider meshCollider = tileObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();

        Mesh tileMesh = new Mesh();

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4]
        {
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(tileSize, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(tileSize, 0f, tileSize),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, tileSize)
        };

        int[] triangles = new int[6] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[4]
        {
            new Vector2(0f, 0f),
            new Vector2(1f, 0f),
            new Vector2(1f, 1f),
            new Vector2(0f, 1f)
        };

        tileMesh.vertices = vertices;
        tileMesh.triangles = triangles;
        tileMesh.uv = uv;

        tileMesh.RecalculateNormals();

        meshFilter.mesh = tileMesh;
        meshRenderer.material = tileMaterial;

        tileObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(tileSize, 0.01f, tileSize);
        tileObject.transform.position = new Vector3(x * tileSize, 0f, z * tileSize);

        meshCollider.sharedMesh = tileMesh;
        meshCollider.convex = true;
       }
}
```

Without Rotation:

[image: GameObject in original position.]

180 Degrees:

[image: GameObject in rotated.]

Comment: This is because of CW/CCW... Just change the indices your array triangles from { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 } to { 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2 }

Comment: @Thomas I'd upvote an answer that explained this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a mesh from code, it is important to know that you need to display them in clockwise (CW) in order for the triangles to face the camera. If you put them in counter clock wise (CCW), they will face away from the camera.

So, in your line of code :

```
int[] triangles = new int[6] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
```

Just change it to

```
int[] triangles = new int[6] { 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2 };
```